# Surviving a plane crash

Tags: riddle, wordplay, lateral-thinking

There were $37$ people onboard on a flight from **Delhi** to **New York**. On its way, plane faced some technical issues and crashed. Every single person on the plane died, yet $4$ people (onboard) survived the crash. How come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is

> They were married. Only **singles** died.

Answer (score 1):

> They were couples or had a spouse. "every **single** person died" (emphasis mine). Thus everyone who wasn't single, survived.